# Recurrence Relation T(n) = T(3/4 * n) + O(1)

Tags: recursion, complexity-theory, recurrence

I'm working out the recurrence relation

`T(n) = T(3/4 * n) + O(1)`

It's coming out to be `O(log(n))`, but I was told before hand that the solution is `O(n)`. I can't find where I'm going wrong - this looks just like the recurrence relation for binary search. Any suggestions?

Comment: Or potentially, the answer I was pre-given is wrong, just trying to find out which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try substituting `T(n) = c*n` or `T(n) = c * log n` into the equation and solving.  One of the two equations will be solvable.

You can also check your answer by evaluating the function for different values of n.

```
-- Define T in your preferred language
t n | n <= 1 = 1 | otherwise = t (3/4 * n) + 1

-- If it's O(log n), then T(n)/log(n) should be asymptotically constant
-- If it's O(n), then T(n)/n should be asymptotically constant
check1 n = t n / log n
check2 n = t n / n

print [check1 1e10, check1 1e11, check1 1e12, check1 1e13]
print [check2 1e10, check2 1e11, check2 1e12, check2 1e13]
```

One of these will converge to a small positive number, the other will go to zero or infinity.

Answer (score 2):

T(n) = T(3/4 * n) + O(1)      ...............(1)
in above eq. T(3/4 * n) is unknown term if you are asking about the solution of this recurrence, then i want to say that we can solve this eq. using substitution method.
in this we have to find out the value of T(3n/4) from main eq. and substitute in the eq. recursively. As this recurrence is depends on recursion.
n=3n/4
T(3n/4)=T((3/4)^2 * n)+ c   ...............(2) notation O replaced by constant c.
now substitute T(3n/4) in (1)
T(n)= T((3/4)^2 * n) +2c     ................(3)
now put n=((3/4)^2 * n) in (1)
T((3/4)^2 * n)=T((3/4)^3 * n)+c
Substitute 
T(n)= T((3/4)^3 * n)+3c      ...............(4)

After kth step eq. will be
T(n)=T((3/4)^k * n)+kc   ................(5) at this step n will be 2 or 1(input size)
(3/4)^k * n= 1
n=(4/3)^k    by taking log on both side.
log(n)=k*log(4/3)
k=log(n)    ..............
place value in eq. (5)
T(n)=T(1)+log(n) * c      ..............(6)
T(n)= O(log n)

Answer (score 1):

The answers that are given are not showing the correct way of solving this kind of recurrences. You case is easily solved with a [Masters theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) and in your case `a=1` and `b=4/3`. This means that `c = logb(a) = 0`.

Because your `f(n)` is a constant, you fall in the second case bucket and where `k=0`. So the solution is [image], where `c = 0` and `k = 0`. This means that:

---

`O(log(n))` is a correct answer